# Video crop command of FFMPEG not work in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-ffmpeg

I am trying to crop video using ffmpeg_kit_flutter package in flutter. But my crop command does not work in Samsung M30 device. This device have Android version 10.In other devices crop command works fine. No error log is display from ffmpeg.

I am using ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl: ^4.5.1 package.

This is my code:

```
        await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(
            "-y -i ${videoPath} -vf crop=in_w:in_h-240 -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -threads 5 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 -c:a copy ${path}",
                (session) async {
              final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
              final failStackTrace = await session.getFailStackTrace();
              print(returnCode);
              print(failStackTrace);
              if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
              }
              else
              {
                String? log=await session.getAllLogsAsString();
                print(log);
              }
            });
```

If anyone has an idea or clue about this issue please help me out.

Comment: any updates on this? I am trying to converting from .mp4 to .mp3 but its not working. I also dont get any logs or stacktrace i could work with

Comment: @Simsala In my case some changes in ffmpeg command solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

[video_trimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer) You can try this Alternate package

Comment: The question talks about "cropping" width and height and not about trimming the length of the video.

Comment: @major akash  I don't want to trim video.